# jquery autocomplete keypress database

Tags: jquery, plugins, autocomplete

I am trying to use jquery autocomplete plugin, I want it to suggest ItemCodes as user types...

The problem is its not showing autocomplete box/frame/....

Just to make sure webmethod returns data on every keyup event, I assigned data to a div element, and it works as it should.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var strItmCodes;

        $("#txtItmCode").keyup(function() {
            var search;
            search = $("#txtItmCode").val();

            if (search.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Journal.aspx/loadData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{'Like':'" + $('#txtItmCode').val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(retval) {
                        strItmCodes = retval.d.split("|");

                        $("#txtItmCode").autocomplete(strItmCodes);
                        $("#suggest").html(retval.d); //elemet 'suggest' is a div
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Modified

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$("#txtItmCode").autocomplete({url: "Journal.aspx/loadData" });

        $("#txtItmCode").keyup(function() {
            $("#txtItmCode").autocomplete({url: "Journal.aspx/loadData" });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should enable the autocomplete plugin before the first keypress, then the plugin will add the event handlers.

Assuming you use the original [autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) plugin:

```
$("#txtItmCode").autocomplete({url: "Journal.aspx/loadData"});
```

And make sure you service can reply to the GET request formatted by the plugin.

Comment: Thanks You for replying solsson!

Yes i am using the original autocomplete pugin, I tried to enable the autocomplete plugin before the first key press.

var strItmCodes;

strItmCodes = "SELECT";

$("#txtItmCode").autocomplete(strItmCodes);


$("#txtItmCode").keyup(function(strItmCodes) {...

but it still does not work.

You also suggested to make sure service (Webmethod) can reply to the GET request, HOW?

Comment: Install Firebug or LiveHTTPHeaders to see the requests sent by the autocomplete plugin

Comment: I edited the post above with correct options parameter to the autocomplete plugin.

Comment: Don't add any event handlers yourself. Just do $("#txtItmCode").autocomplete("Journal.aspx/loadData"); The backend must respond to the query Journal.aspx/loadData?q=[currentvalue]&limit=150&timestamp=1245666452263 with a text/plain response with entries separated with newline (no json or anything)

Comment: Hello Solsson, Many Questions
1) How to make backend (sql server) respond with entries separated with newline  (no json or anything).
2)$("#txtItmCode").autocomplete({url: "Journal.aspx/loadData"});
simply does not work.